# Check_box_tag get index value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Have the following code:

```
<%= form_tag tags_path do %>
        <%= check_box_tag "isCat",  options = {index: @tag.id, class: "checkbox"} %>
        <%= submit_tag "Add",  class:"input-group-addon btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I want in the controller to get the id as an integer. I have failed to get the value at all..

```
def create
  # not working
  a_id = params[:isCat][:index]
end
```

Since I pass it to db procedure the variable must be defined as integer.

Comment: Why are you using a checkbox? Check boxes are true/false (checked/unchecked), they are not appropriate to hold object ids.

Comment: At first I used `hidden_field_tag` but had my problems there to get the an integer out of the value (params returned me `{:value => 3}`). Anyway I saw that the checkbox can hold id value so for me it sound good to remove one object from the page (the hidden field). Anyway best-practice recommendation will be good as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the *attribute identifier* in the `name` part of `check_box_tag`, try

```
<%= form_tag tags_path do %>
    <%= check_box_tag "isCat[index]", @tag.id, class: "checkbox" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Add",  class:"input-group-addon btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: You also should add `to_i` on `params[:isCat][:index]`

Comment: Thanks. If you also think Simore right, can you please update with the correct way to put and retrieve `id` from `form_tag`?

Comment: @nir What would be your context in storing and retrieving an `id`? You can use `session`, or `hidden_field_tag` like you mentioned above (what issue do you experience with hidden_field_tag?).

Comment: The idea is to save some data to the DB, the data is not related to the model but I do use the `id` as a referance. Getting an integer value from `hidden_field_tag` was the problem.

Comment: @nir Can you elaborate what problem you're experiencing with `hidden_field_tag`? Have you tried `<%= hidden_field_tag "isCat[index]", @tag.id, class: "checkbox" %>`? It'll be included in `params` as `params[:isCat][:index]` on form submission.

Comment: @nir You're welcome. Beware that the user can tamper with this, and this should be avoided for sensitive information.

Comment: Is there preferred alternative?

Comment: @nir You can use the `session` hash, more details here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark